# Trace -logarithm - matrix

Tags: matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, trace

How do I calculate this, $\beta$ is a parameter, $H$ a matrix:

$(1-\beta \partial_\beta)\ln(Tr(e^{-\beta H})) = \ln(Tr(e^{-\beta H})) - \beta \frac{\partial_\beta Tr(e^{-\beta H})}{Tr(e^{-\beta H})}=?$

Are there identities to simplify $\ln(Tr)$ and my derivative?

Comment: If you know the eigenvalues $\lambda_1,...\lambda_n$ of the matrix $H$,
$$Tr \big(e^{-\beta \hat H}\big)=Tr \big(I-\beta \,diag(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n)+\frac{\beta^2}{2!} \,diag(\lambda_1^2,...,\lambda_n^2)+...\big)=diag\big(e^{-\beta\lambda_1}, ...,e^{-\beta\lambda_n}\big)$$

Answer (score 0):

$
\def\a{\alpha}\def\b{\beta}\def\l{\lambda}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\tr{\operatorname{Tr}}
$For typing convenience, let a dot denote derivatives wrt $\b$ and define the variables
$$\eqalign{
E &= \exp(-\b H) &\qiq \dot E = -HE \\
\a &= \tr(E) &\qiq \dot\a = \tr(\dot E)\\
\l &= \log(\a) &\qiq\dot\l = \frac{\dot\a}{\a}
 = \left(\frac{-\tr(HE)}{\tr(E)}\right)  \\
}$$
Substituting this into your equation yields
$$\eqalign{
\big(\l - \b\dot\l\big) = \l \;+\; \frac{\tr(\b HE)}{\tr(E)} \\
}$$